# Returning a validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this `LoginController`. The `LoginModel` is able to provide validation on string lengths and required fields. This is displayed fine in the razor page.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.NotPublicPc);
                var url = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.Username, model.NotPublicPc);
                return Redirect(url);
            }
            else
            {
                //here I want to throw my own validation message or otherwise
                //give feedback that the login was unsuccessful
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Keep me logged in - do not check on public computer")]
    public bool NotPublicPc { get; set; }
}
```

How do I throw my own validation error - i.e. I want to show a message when the login fails. Though I now appreciate the validation for required and length is done in the browser so this is different.

I have tried throwing `Exception` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw an exception that is not handled the client will receive an http 500 error (unless you throw an `HttpException` and specify a error number). If that is desireable then thats what you can do. Otherwise you can try to add an error message to your model state:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "Error Message");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some of my code for a "Semester" example field in ASP.NET MVC:

```
[Display(Name = "Semester:"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in the Semester of the Issue"), StringLength(25)]
```

This specifically will throw the error message if the field is empty.

You can also add Regular Expressions, if you'd like. ie:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$", ErrorMessage = "Link format is wrong")]
```

This code will check to make sure that a URL is in the proper format.

This should be pretty close to what you're looking for, although if it is not, I will be happy to remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom error:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "YOUR ERROR");
```

This will add an error with the text "YOUR ERROR" and no associated property, meaning it will only be shown in the validation summary. If you add a property name instead of `String.Empty` it should be shown as an error of that property.

You can also pass an exception as the second parameter, but I never used that, so I do not know what the output will be...